# R read target programmatically

Tags: r, nse, targets-r-package

I have a set of targets, lets say `data_a`, `data_b`, ...
I want to iterate over all datasets and load the data.
This can be achieved using `tar_read(data_a)` or `tar_read(data_a")`. As I want to load the targets programmatically, I would like to use something like this in some kind of lapply:

```
target_name <- "data_a"
data <- tar_read(target_name)
```

But then I get the error that the target `target_name` was not found.
I know this is related to NSE with R as `tar_read` internally calls `substitute`, but I wasn't able to figure out how to mask the `target_name` to make `tar_read` work. I have tried `eval(parse())` and the different options presented in [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html), as well as rlang (such as !!, {{ and similar) to no avail.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the code for `tar_read`, you see that it uses NSE to convert the `name` parameter into a character string, then calls the function `tar_read_raw` on the resulting string:

```r
tar_read
#> function (name, branches = NULL, meta = tar_meta(store = store), 
#      store = targets::tar_config_get("store")) 
#> {
#>     force(meta)
#>     name <- tar_deparse_language(substitute(name))
#>     tar_read_raw(name = name, branches = branches, meta = meta, 
#>         store = store)
#> }
```

However, you can also use `tar_read_raw` directly. The manual for `tar_read_raw` says:

> Like `tar_read()` except `name` is a character string.

So you should just be able to do:

```r
data <- tar_read_raw(target_name)
```

Comment: Insert facepalm here.... Thanks for the hint and the solution!

Comment: This does not work inside a quarto repo. It shows a warning `Warning message:
targets loaded with tar_load_raw() or tar_read_raw() will not be detected as dependencies in literate programming reports. To properly register target dependencies of reports, use tar_load() or tar_read() instead.`. Any other solution?